# Timing between 7-segment display and enable

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I am working through Altera University LABS but I am using a board of a slightly different design so I am having to mimic the way the boards used in the labs display to 7 Segment LED.

I have sorted it out with the code below:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY DE1_disp IS
   PORT ( HEX0, HEX1, HEX2, HEX3: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
             clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
             HEX : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
             DISPn: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END DE1_disp;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF DE1_disp IS
   COMPONENT sweep 
       Port ( mclk      : in  STD_LOGIC;
              sweep_out : out  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
   END COMPONENT;

   SIGNAL M : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN -- Behavior

    S0: sweep PORT MAP (clk,M); 

    DISPProcess: process (clk,M) is
    begin
       CASE M IS
            WHEN "00" => HEX <= HEX0; DISPn <= "1110"; 
            WHEN "01" => HEX <= HEX1; DISPn <= "1101";
            WHEN "10" => HEX <= HEX2; DISPn <= "1011";
            WHEN "11" => HEX <= HEX3; DISPn <= "0111"; 
        END CASE;
    end process DISPProcess;

END Behavior;
```

The gist is that my board has one lot of segment drivers and you have to scan the LED enable.  Whilst the LAB boards simply have n sets of segment drivers.

The code above works except for a pesky "ghost" character.  What appears to be happening is that the enable is likely held low whilst a character change is occurring so the following display is lit for a poofteenth enable time.

As you can see from the code I am taking four 7-segment display inputs and generating a scanned and the ghost is always on the digit following the last enable - so it will also wrap from 4th to 1st display.  Obviously, this is most apparent when a display is blanked.

For the purposes of the labs this code is fine.  However, I would love to better understand what I have done to incur the ghost as understanding that would help me understand VHDL design a tad more.

Can anyone please suggested then what principle I need to grasp here or at least how to code up the enable so it falls after the digit change?

Note I have tried a default case (both using NULL and setting DISPn to "1111").  I suspect a way to do it is to expand case statement and alternatively set HEX and then set DISPn on successive case statements.  But are there any other VHDL tricks that might work?

Cheers,
A

Comment: Hard to pinpoint the problem... I would try to register the output (enclose everything in `DISPProcess` in a `if rising_edge(clk) then` statement).

Comment: Yep, tried that as well.  Tried pulling the enable out into a separate process.  Beefed up the scan from 4 to 8 values so I could drive the segment change on odd scan values and the enable on even.  I set the default of the enable process to disable all displays.  Tried clocking the segment driver and enable driver on combinations of rising and falling edges etc.  So I think it is something fundamental to the way I designed this.

Comment: Actually,  I finally got rid of the "ghost" by taking the view I did not want the  enable set until the display was set so I pulled the DISPn code into a WHEN-ELSE assignment based upon values in M.  The quirk was if I kept a 2bit M I still got the ghost but if I went to a 3bit M and used every 0,2,4,6 as selection values, for enabling (and thus every other value for disabling) the ghost disappears.  Still some work to understand why the 3bit M and alternate values of M were needed to sort the problem but now I can work out why it works from here.  All, I might add, without using edges.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your diagnosis is slightly wrong.

Check the schematic for your board : it is likely that the Enables (called `Disp`) drive the bases of bipolar transistors into saturation. Then - even though `Hex` and `Disp` change in the same delta cycle, charge storage in the external transistors maintain the Enable for long enough to see the ghost.

The fix is to provide a dead time, turning the Enables off for a short while until the enable transistors are fully off - probably 10's of microseconds - then you can change the digit and re-enable at  the same time.

Your solution accomplishes this elegantly simply, but at the cost of half the potential brightness.

Comment: That is a good observation.  In fact, the solution I found (which is still a little clunky in my opinion but works for this situation) was to use a 3 bit counter, instead of two bit, and to ensure DISPn was driven "1111" every odd clock cycle and only driving the enable of the 7-segment display on even cycles.

Comment: Brian, that is a good observation.  Looking at the [schematic](https://organicmonkeymotion.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/altera-fpga-development-board-user-manual.pdf) that is exactly what the problem appears to have been.